# Need To Get The Max Repeated Value in Column iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using sqllite Data Base.

I have a table (named contact) with Row's named: 
ID , Page , Lat , lon , outDate

I Need To Get the Max. repeated Value in Page And Out The Other Column Values only For THis Max value How Can I Do That

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to first isolate the max repeated value of the Page column, and then use this value in a subquery to select all of the contact rows that match it.

To isolate the max repeated value of the page column you can use a group by clause which will group all of the result rows together by the value of 'Page' in that row. If you order these in a descending manner by the number of rows that match this value of 'Page', and then only take the top row, you have the max repeated value of 'Page'.

```
select * from contact where Page in (
select Page from contact group by Page order by count(*) desc limit 1)
```